# Execution cost exists when accessing a public variable, but not paid by the caller

Tags: evm

When I execute the code below on Remix VM and call the `number` variable, I can see from the call details that there is an execution cost of 2407 gas.

```
contract HelloWorld {
    uint256 public number = 0;
}
```

My understanding is that accessing a public variable on a contract does not result in a cost for the caller. In that case, what is the definition of ‘execution cost’ and who is responsible for paying it on an actual blockchain network?

Answer (score 0):

You may see `execution cost` for `2407 gas` in Remix VM as a result of deploying and executing the contract itself rather than accessing it.